# Silencing :make command

Tags: makeprg

I am setting `makeprg` to `perl %` to run my Perl script (if there's a better way, I'm up for that, too), and it works just fine, except that it reproduces the first line of output prefixed with the text "(1 of n)", where n seems to be the total output line count.

I'd like to suppress that, leaving me with just what my Perl script produces.  Can I suppress that report line from `:make`?  The .vimrc line that sets up makeprg is:

```
autocmd FileType perl   :set makeprg=perl\ %
```

Comment: you probably want to not use `:make` but instead map K key to `:!perl %` (or even `:%w!perl`)

Comment: @Naumann K is usually used for documentation, make for running or compiling programs. I think this is the appropriate way to go.

Comment: RadlyEel, have you tried using the :compiler command to set the makeprg? Im sure perl has some native support in Vim... do you have filetype plugins enabled?

Comment: Thanks to both.  I didn't like K, but F5 is a commonly used "Run" command in other IDEs, so I used it and that worked perfectly.  Using the :compiler command only gives me syntax checking.  And there's no user input in this approach, so for interactive scripts I have to use the two-terminal approach.  There is a Perl mode in Vim, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

### Plugin [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) by Tim Pope

This plugin provides as one of its main features running `makeprg` non-blocking either in the foreground or the background. Quote from `:h dispatch`:

> Leverage the power of Vim's compiler system without being constrained by
>   synchronicity.

The first command by vim-dispatch is `:Make` (note the capital `M`):

```
:Make [arguments]       Using the current |:compiler| settings, dispatch a
                        build in the foreground.  Adapter strategies vary, but
                        the goal is visibility without stealing focus.  When
                        the build is complete, load the results into the
                        |quickfix| list and call |:cwindow|.  This command is
                        preferred for shorter tasks like "build this file."
```

Let us consider this hello world perl file without errors which has as output two lines

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello world\n";
print 42, "\n";
```

Set `makeprg` as the OP suggested or manually with

`:se mp=perl\ %` (abbreviated form of `makeprg` is `mp`)

Now press either `m<CR>` or type `:Make<CR>` from vim-dispatch. Perl will be executed and the 
output will be available in the quickfix window without any additional lines:

[image]

The OP might be interested in having the quickfix window automatically be opened or keeping it open during scripting & running. Unfortunately, I could not figure this out. But someone has already filed this as a feature request on [github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/issues/226#issuecomment-394099194).

Other plugins provide this but are heavier plugins such as:

- [Neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake#usage)
- [AsyncRun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim#quickfix-window)

#### vim-dispatch as of 2019

- supports vim8/neovim jobs (no tmux/screen/iterm needed anymore)
- nice (IMHO) default mappings

  - `m<cr>` for `:Make`
  - `m<Space>` for `:Make<space>` (e.g. allows the user to run `make debug`)
  - and more (see `:h dispatch-maps`)
- [Pending PR #250](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/pull/250) and [active branch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/tree/reuse-terminal) to use vim8/neovim terminal for `:Start` to [spawn interactive processes](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch#spawning-interactive-processes).

Answer (score 0):

`autocmd BufRead *.pl map <F5> :exe ':silent !perl %'<CR>:redr!<CR>`

This defines an [autocmd](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4hrmgp4LYAhVIORoKHZixA1MQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvimdoc.sourceforge.net%2Fhtmldoc%2Fautocmd.html&usg=AOvVaw12cDtpSqZ40geXlyYoNRx2) for perl files.
If <kbd>F5</kbd> is pressed, the current file will be sent to the perl interpreter, afterwards the buffer is redrawn, so you will not see any output.