# Compile LaTeX source file in the background without any plugin

Tags: key-bindings

I am new to Vim and I would like to make a key binding to compile my LaTeX source. I have the following

```
autocmd FileType tex :nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :!pdflatex %<CR>
```

which is working very well but **I would like it to run in the background**.
I know there are options with `<silent>` but I can't make them work.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Are you ok with plugin suggestions? Many plugins for latex compilation exist. Also, by background, do you mean "I don't care about the output on screen and don't want to see it" ?

Comment: related question https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/silencing-make-command/21094#21094

Comment: There has been a discussion on the vim mailing list to include a plugin to $VIMRUNTIME similar to vim-dispatch which Bram is open to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_use/2-_o4LKzt2s/j3SvGoCBDQAJ

Comment: You might want to consider using vimtex plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a non-disruptive process to run, consider tpope's Dispatch plugin: if you have a `makeprg` setup well for LaTex, you could use it's `:Make`; otherwise, you'll want to `:Start pdflatex ...`.

To silence a *mapping*, use `nnoremap <silent> ...`. But note that this just prevents echoing of the simulated characters being typed.

To silence a command, do `:silent[!] command`. With `!`, all error messages are suppressed.

Comment: Could you provide an example with `:silent[!]` ?

Comment: @Dave `:silent! make` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim's `job_start()` function to run a command asynchronously. This does not require any plugins, but does require Vim to be compiled with the `+job` feature (you can check this by running the `:version` command).

Here's a long one-liner to apply your command:

```vim
autocmd FileType tex :nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <F5>
    \ :let b:job = job_start(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'pdflatex ' . expand('%:p')])<CR>
```

Notes:

- The `pdflatex` command only works if your tex file is in Vim's current working directory. So you may want to consider using `latexmk` instead, which provides a `-cd` option.
- I've noticed that in some cases, `job_start()` will slightly mess up the screen. If this happens, you may want to add a callback function to redraw the screen (see [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20481/16602) to a related question).

Comment: `job_start` is just the start. We should also register callback for filling in the quickfix list, and taking care of the execution end, and also failures at the start. In the end, this is what plugins do.

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to do this is by using [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) to send the compilation command to another terminal. I like this method because it behaves as if you had typed the command in that terminal yourself.

Add this to your `.vimrc`  (note this code uses `latexmk` instead of `pdflatex`):

```vim
function! TmuxSend()
    let tex_file = expand('%:p')
    let tex_cmd = 'latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -cd ' . tex_file
    let tmux_cmd = 'tmux send-keys -t vim_output.0 "' . tex_cmd . '" ENTER'
    let output = system(tmux_cmd)   
endfunction

autocmd FileType tex :nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <F5> :call TmuxSend()<CR>
```

Now, open another terminal and create a tmux session named "vim_output": `tmux new-session -s vim_output`. Now, when you press <kbd>F5</kbd> in Vim, the `latexmk` command will be run in the terminal you just created.